# Possible to use SharedPreferences in a fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, sharedpreferences

I try to use

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("TEST", 123);
editor.commit();
```

in a Fragment: `public class FragmentStatistics extends Fragment { ...`
`public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){...`

Is this possible? It gives me a debugger error.

Thanks in advance. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Can u show the complete code ?  It should be possible to use sharedpreference from fragment using the application context.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("TEST", 123);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Please take your time to format the answer, or edit it after you post it. Also, try to explain to the OP **why** you answered with this code, it's the only way to share knowledge instead of building a site in which people get cut-and-paste code when they have a problem (without having to do some reasoning). [How to answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)